# How do I position a link at the bottom of a responsive landing page with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position a circular instagram icon so it is always centered towards the bottom of a landing page. All my efforts so far such as using position:fixed; have resulted in the icon not remaining underneath the rest of my content when the screen size changes.

My html is like this:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>RBM Makeup</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<section class="intro">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="content">
            <h1> Rebecca Bermingham Maguire</h1>
            <div class="container">
                <a href="#" class="hvr-sweep-to-right">Portfolio</a>
                <a href="#" class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom">Contact</a>
                <a href="#" class="hvr-sweep-to-left">About Me</a>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <div class="instagram">
            <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram" id="fix"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>
</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS is like this:

```
   :root{
    --maroon: #85144b;
    --fuchsia: #f012be;
    --purple: #b10dc9;
    --lime: #01ff70;
    --black: #000000;
    --white: #ffffff;
    --blue: #89cff0;
}

@font-face{
    font-family: 'milkshake';
    src:url(fonts/Milkshake.ttf);
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
}

@font-face{
    font-family: 'amble';
    src:url(fonts/Amble-Regular.ttf);
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
}

html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

/**/

.intro{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    background: url("images/eye.jpg") no-repeat 50% 50%;
    display: table;
    top: 0;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0.92;
}

.intro .inner{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
}

.content h1{
    color: var(--black);
    font-size: 350%;
    margin: 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: bold;
    font-family: milkshake;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.container a{
    border-radius: 9px;
    color: var(--black);
    font-size: 135%;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: solid var(--black) 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 20px 40px;
    font-family: amble;
    font-weight: 150;
    font-style: bold;
}

/*Instagram Icon*/

.fa {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 55px;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  align-content: center;
}

.fa:hover{
    opacity:0.7;
}

.fa-instagram {
  background: var(--black);
  color: var(--white);
}

.footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;   
    height: 100px;
    left: 47.5%;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified two places of your code.

### 1. `.foot`

`left: 50% plus margin-left:  - { width } / 2` can make footer align center no matter how the window changes.

```

```
.footer {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 95px; // here
      height: 100px;
      left: 50%; // here
      margin-left: calc(-95px / 2); // here
    }
```

```

### 2. `.fa`

In your code, the Instagram icon is not aligning center inside the black circle, so I make some changes for it.

As the Instagram icon is square, you should not set the `width` 40px when it's `font-size` is 55px.

```

```
.fa {
          padding: 20px;
          font-size: 55px;
          width: 55px; /* here */
          text-align: center;
          text-decoration: none;
          border-radius: 50%;
          align-content: center;
        }
```

```

If you have more questions about my answer, feel free to contact me :)

```css
:root {
      --maroon: #85144b;
      --fuchsia: #f012be;
      --purple: #b10dc9;
      --lime: #01ff70;
      --black: #000000;
      --white: #ffffff;
      --blue: #89cff0;
    }

    @font-face {
      font-family: 'milkshake';
      src: url(fonts/Milkshake.ttf);
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 100;
    }

    @font-face {
      font-family: 'amble';
      src: url(fonts/Amble-Regular.ttf);
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 100;
    }

    html,
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }

    /**/

    .intro {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin-right: 20px;
      margin: auto;
      background: url("images/eye.jpg") no-repeat 50% 50%;
      display: table;
      top: 0;
      background-size: cover;
      opacity: 0.92;
    }

    .intro .inner {
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: none;
    }

    .content h1 {
      color: var(--black);
      font-size: 350%;
      margin: 0px 0px;
      text-align: center;
      text-transform: bold;
      font-family: milkshake;
      font-weight: 100;
    }

    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      justify-content: center;
      margin-top: 50px;
    }

    .container a {
      border-radius: 9px;
      color: var(--black);
      font-size: 135%;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      text-decoration: none;
      border: solid var(--black) 5px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      margin: 20px 40px;
      font-family: amble;
      font-weight: 150;
      font-style: bold;
    }

    /*Instagram Icon*/

    .fa {
      padding: 20px;
      font-size: 55px;
      width: 55px; /* need to fit the font-size */
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      border-radius: 50%;
      align-content: center;
    }

    .fa:hover {
      opacity: 0.7;
    }

    .fa-instagram {
      background: var(--black);
      color: var(--white);
    }

    .footer {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 95px;
      height: 100px;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: calc(-95px / 2);
    }
```

```html
<section class="intro">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="content">
        <h1> Rebecca Bermingham Maguire</h1>
        <div class="container">
          <a href="#" class="hvr-sweep-to-right">Portfolio</a>
          <a href="#" class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom">Contact</a>
          <a href="#" class="hvr-sweep-to-left">About Me</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      <div class="instagram">
        <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram" id="fix"></a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

set the parent as

```
.intro {
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  position:relative;
}
```

and the icon element as

```
.footer {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:50%;
  width:40px;
  margin-left:-20px;
}
```

as an alternative:

```
.footer {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
.footer > div {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

this will do better as you can add other elements if you end up wanting to add other links